# Issue while saving using Entity Framework Core with constraint

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I have a table `UserSession` with `CreatedTime` column of `datetime` not null type. In that table, I created a constraint on this column like this:

```sql
CONSTRAINT [CK__UserSession__CreatedTi__690797E6] CHECK ([CreatedTime] <= GETUTCDATE())
```

When I try to save the new entity to database like this

```cs
var newSession = new UserSession
{
    // ...
    CreatedTime = DateTime.UtcNow
};
_dbContext.UserSessions.Add(newSession);
await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

it throws an exception about the save progress was failed like this

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException : An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
>
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CK__UserSession__CreatedTi__33D4B598". The conflict occurred in database "testdb", table "dbo.UserSession", column 'CreatedTime'.

It looks like the saved entity is violating the constraint.

So how can I resolve this saving data issue with an entity like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be issues with `DateTime` synchronization between your app server/client where the value is populated, and the database which is performing the constraint check.

For things like created Date-Time values I recommend letting the database handle populating these when rows are created. Set a default on the column as part of the constraint to use `GETUTCDATE()`, then mark the entity as a computed column:

```
    [DateTimeKind(DateTimeKind.Utc), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public DateTime CreatedTime { get; protected set; }
```

Now you don't need to explicitly set the value, the property won't let you use the setter in any case. When a row is inserted it will get the current UTC timestamp filled in.

Comment: I removed the constraint in that column (`CreatedTime datetime DEFAULT getutcdate() NOT NULL`) and also add the attribute in the mapped field in code but it doesn't work. it throws another exception which says cannot insert null value, althougt I set the default value for it (`public DateTime CreatedTime { get; protected set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;`)

Comment: also I can't find any attribute named `[DateTimeKind(DateTimeKind.Utc)]` in your answer

Comment: You said you removed the constraint in the column but there is still a not null constraint ?? `CreatedTime datetime DEFAULT getutcdate() NOT NULL`

Comment: This is the most straightforward answer - let the DB add the created date time. Otherwise, you will have to work out 1) what time the DB server is on and 2) what time the client(s) is (are) on and 3) Are the clients and servers correctly understanding the time zones of the dates they are receiving from each other. For instance, the server may receive a UTC date but think it is a local date and so on and so on.

Comment: For this to work, the database schema needs to be update to set the Default value for new rows to `GETUTCDATE()`. This can be done in the SSMS designer by selecting the column in the table designer and setting the default value property, or using an update schema script to set a column default. (See topsail's comment)