# Issue while saving using Entity Framework Core with datetime columns constraint

Tags: sql, .net, entity-framework-core, constraints

(this is another side, something similar but the others are difference to this question which was answered [Issue while saving using Entity Framework Core with constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78144378/issue-while-saving-using-entity-framework-core-with-constraint))

I have a table `UserSession` with `CreatedTime` column of `datetime` not null type and `LastUpdateTime` column with `datetime` nullable type. In that table, I created a constraint on these 2 columns like this:

```sql
[CreatedTime] [DATETIME] NOT NULL DEFAULT GETUTCDATE(),
[LastUpdateTime] [DATETIME] NULL,
CONSTRAINT CK__UserSession__CreatedTime__LastUpdateTime CHECK
(
    [LastUpdateTime] IS NULL
    OR (
        [CreatedTime] <= [LastUpdateTime]
        AND [LastUpdateTime] <= GETUTCDATE() -- remove this line should run correctly
    )
)
```

When I try to update an existing entity to database like this

```cs
var session = await _dbContext.UserSessions.FindAsync(id);
session.LastUpdateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
_dbContext.UserSessions.Add(newSession);
await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

it throws an exception about the save progress was failed like this

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException : An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
>
> ----> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : The UPDATE statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CK__UserSession__CreatedTime__LastUpdateTime". The conflict occurred in database "testdb", table "dbo.UserSession".
>
> The statement has been terminated.

It looks like the saved entity is violating the constraint.

```sql
AND [LastUpdateTime] <= GETUTCDATE()
```

Business note: when an entity is created for the first time, the `LastUpdateTime` is null. after any column of this record is updated, the `LastUpdateTime` will be updated to utc time

So how can I resolve this saving data issue with an entity like this?

Comment: This will likely be that you cannot guarantee that your web server or client app time is synchronized with your database server where UTC Date  generated ends up being recognized as a later time on the database. If you want to ensure values are reasonably accurate then you might consider using something like a 5 minute tolerance on the value check.

Comment: @StevePy they are located in the same machine, and all the code (in c#) / query (in sql) are set to use utc time (DateTime.UtcNow and GetUTCDate()). I think I'm missing some configurations in database server

Comment: Hmm, could try adding ` [DateTimeKind(DateTimeKind.Utc)]` above the LastUpdateTime property in case it might somehow be getting confused and thinking it was a local time value when converting to SQL. Otherwise remove the check from the constraint and insert a row and inspect the SentTime vs the LastUpdateTime for clues since SentTime should be set at that point to `GetUTCDate` based on the default. Make sure both the time AND date for the LastUpdateTime are correct. SQL Server may have a different date format which the SQL Server is inserting a row for the wrong date.

Comment: Ran into issue long time ago because EF assumes DateTime2(7) and when comparing to DateTime column in database the comparison isn't what you expect because of the different number of fractional seconds.  We saw the issue comparing a column against itself and it frequently would not match.  You could be seeing the same thing comparing <=.

Comment: @StevePy as I mention in question, the check constraint AND [LastUpdateTime] <= GETUTCDATE() make the code fail as it 's violating the whole constraint

Comment: @ScottMildenberger there might be something different between database time and dotnet time so it may impact to the constraint. does the timezone impact to the code and sql database?

Comment: Yes, so temporarily remove that part of the constraint and insert a record, then look at the data for the LastUpdateTime (populated by c#) and the CreatedTime (populated by SQL) Look at these complete values in the database. Ensure the date component is correct, (not an date format conversion issue from SQL) then look at the millisecond component as well.